# "Invalid JSON Payload Error" received when performing a structured query using Google Sheets API v4

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

When i try this link from Google Docs, to filter my sheet based on the `username` parameter:

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetid/values:batchGet?username="andika_1317"&key=mykey
```

I receive a response like this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"username\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'username' could not be found in request message.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"username\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'username' could not be found in request message."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I don't know why I get the error response, since in the table I've created a `username` field:
[image]

How can I perform these queries with the Sheets API?

Comment: There is no query parameter for ``username`` at [spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet). So the error occurs.

Comment: so what i do to get the data with username condition? @Tanaike

Comment: Do you want to search some values on spreadsheet?

Comment: ya, i want search value with condition like in sql querry ex: select * from [table] where username=[value] @Tanaike

Comment: Is this information useful for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48511747/using-google-query-to-download-parts-of-a-published-sheet/48512382#48512382

Comment: thanks for the link, but i think that is not what i looking for

Comment: I'm really sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: its okay, thank you for trying help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle structured queries for retrieving rows with Google Sheets API v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42463608/how-to-handle-structured-queries-for-retrieving-rows-with-google-sheets-api-v4)